# Unblanking a Linux Terminal Display

Tags: troubleshooting, display

I am running an Ubuntu Server that boots to the console. After a long wile, the screen goes blank and I cannot type or unblank the screen. Even the caps lock / num lock do not change states. I am however, able to SSH into the computer.

Is there a way I can unblank the tty1 over SSH?

Is it possible to do this from the keyboard + not logged in + blank screen?

Comment: Try changing the terminals (as root): `chvt 2; chvt 1` (to VT2, then to VT1).

Comment: That did something. Changing to vt2 changed the state of numlock and back to VT1 restored it. But it did not unblank the screen. I typed my credentials blink on VT2 and logged in. I see myself by typing `who` over ssh. But the screen is still blank! :-(

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: This is the same as setting `/sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank` to 0. It is already 0.

Comment: try `setterm -blank poke`

Comment: That cannot be done from ssh. `setterm: cannot force unblank: Inappropriate ioctl for device` I tried `setterm -blank poke -term tty1` and `-term /dev/tty1` neither worked.

Comment: Yes, you would have to run it on the blanked console, I'm afraid.

Comment: That did not work either. Even `sudo reboot` did not bring the display up. I always have to hard power it off and power it on. It was fine when I was using Mint 14.

Comment: Just rebooted with the links that @MichaelDurrant pointed. I am back to square one. Blank display that will not unblank!

Comment: Hm and did `sudo reboot` actually reboot the machine?

Comment: Yes. I saw the disk blink and `uptime` is a small and reasonable number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10941/discussion-between-peterph-and-lord-loh)

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238846/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working answer on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/137728/how-do-i-permanently-disable-linuxs-console-screen-saver-system-wide) from [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1nx11e/unblanking_a_linux_terminal_display/ccni9r4).

Even though I did disable blanking, the screen still goes blank, but I can bring it back with a key press. I can live with that for now.

The trick was to install `console-tools` and configure it from `/etc/console-tools/config` to have

```
BLANK_TIME=0
POWERDOWN_TIME=0
```

Added on 2013-11-15:
After an update, this broke down again! The display would blank and never unblank. This time I had to update the file in `/etc/kbd/config`. After fixing the file the computer remained on all night without blanking the display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
setterm -blank poke --term linux < /dev/tty1
```

Comment: This worked for me on a Raspberry Pi. Needed sudo.